# how can I add Coinbase base as a payment system to my website?

Tags: laravel, coinbase-api

I want to add Coinbase as a payment methods to my laravel website. Can anyone give me the documentation of coinbase commerce api?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This portal is a Q/A site. No one can't upload or send documentation to you.

Comment: I mean any link of documentation. Not a pdf or any kind of file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add coinbase payment system to your website then I suggest you read and follow the official documentation from coinbase regarding a payment system for your website.

I found this from coinbase, - https://help.coinbase.com/en/pro/getting-started/adding-a-payment-method/adding-a-payment-method

Comment: I guess, it's for trading purpose. But I want something like payment gateway, as like as stripe or paypal payment gateway.

Comment: Have you any  a big firm ?

Comment: Sorry. what do you mean by firm?